# Lexical environment and memory in self-scheduling functions

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

Does this kind of code have a memory leak:

```html
let n = 0;

function foo() {
    const str = '...long string' + (++n);
    setImmediate(() => {
        console.log('str=' + str);
        foo();
    });
}

foo();
```

I'm asking because, as I understand, each function's lexical environment has a pointer to the lexical environment in which the function was created. So it seems like in the above we will have a growing chain of lexical environments.

If so, what is the pattern to get around this problem? If not, what is the error with the reasoning above?

Comment: The callback to `setImmediate()` will be invoked after each invocation of `foo()` has completely finished, so at any given time only one `foo()` will be active.

Comment: Yeah, but won't the active one have a pointer to the lexical environment of the one that previously ran so it can e.g. access local variables declared there?

Comment: Interesting point, but still it seems like there will then be two contexts at any time, because once a callback terminates its reference to the previous `foo()` context will no longer be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each function's lexical environment has a pointer to the lexical environment in which the function was created.

Yes.

> So it seems like in the above we will have a growing chain of lexical environments.

No. `foo` has a pointer to the outer lexical environment in which `n` is declared. Each of the arrow functions that are getting created is having a pointer to the lexical environment in which `str` is declared (which in turn is linked to the outer one).

But calling `foo()` again does not grow the chain, it only creates a new environment for that function call, linked to the outer environment (with `n`) and declares a new `str` in it.

> Won't the active one have a pointer to the lexical environment of the one that previously ran so it can e.g. access local variables declared there?

No. The pointer that is used when the function is called only depends on where the function was defined, not what was active before.

Comment: Thanks, as I understand, there can only be at most 2 lexical environments of foo() referenced at a time: specifically when executing the function in setImmediate(), one will be of foo() invocation that called setImmediate(), another will be of foo() invocation inside setImmediate().  When setImmediate() finished, the 1st one can be deallocated.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.